# Java generics, how to correctly cast child to method?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to work with generics and unable to figure out the below

```
public abstract class AbstractPage {
}

public class GlossyPage extends AbstractPage {
    private PaperStyle<GlossyPage> paperStyle = new PaperStyle<>(this);
    public PaperStyle styles() {
        return paperStyle;
    }
}

public class PaperStyle<T extends AbstractPage> {
    private final T page;

    public PaperStyle(T page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public <T> T build() {
        return (T) page;
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
GlossyPage page = new GlossyPage()
    .styles()
    .<GlossyPage> build();
```

However, this does not work and compiler complains to add a cast like below. Is the above not possible?

```
GlossyPage page = (GlossyPage) new Book()
    .styles()
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The reason was I need to appropriately cast the method:

```
public class GlossyPage extends AbstractPage {
    private PaperStyle<GlossyPage> paperStyle = new PaperStyle<>(this);
    public PaperStyle<GlossyPage> styles() {
        return paperStyle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a new (different) type variable for build().  Changing your method to:

```java
    public T build() {                                                          
        return page;                                                            
    }
```

shoud fix it.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work, the compiler still complains and asks me to add a cast like so: (GlossyPage) new GlossyPage().  I want to be able to cast to the build() method instead, like:  <GlossyPage> build().